# Why can't I use Async Components in routes with Vue Router 4?

Tags: asynchronous, components, vue-router

The documentation at https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html says: "Do not use Async components for routes." Why not? I want to do that and I have been doing that in the past.

It actually worked with Vue 3.0.11 and Vue Router 4.0.6, but it does not work with Vue 3.2.9 and Vue Router 4.0.11. I used to be able to pass props through the router view like this: <router-view :device="device"></router-view> but not anymore. What could be a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

By *Do not use `Async components`* Router documentation says *do not use Vue 3 async components* [as described in Vue 3 documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#async-components)

**Do not:**

```js
import { defineAsyncComponent  } from "vue"

const UserDetails = defineAsyncComponent (() => import('./views/UserDetails'))

const router = createRouter({
  // ...
  routes: [{ path: '/users/:id', component: UserDetails }],
})
```

**Do: (...well as you did before Vue 3)**

```js
const UserDetails = () => import('./views/UserDetails')

const router = createRouter({
  // ...
  routes: [{ path: '/users/:id', component: UserDetails }],
})
```

More info in [Migration Guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#overview)